# Vuejs Html tag / attribute in data()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to do {{item.icon}} pull as a html data not string but ı don't know how to do that, is there are anyway to do that please help me out

I have this code:

```
    <div class="box my-5" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" >
        <div class="innerBox">
            <router-link to="/ninethPage">
                <div  class="card Fcard d-flex  flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="padding: 1rem 2rem !important">
                    <span v-html="icon"> </span>
                    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
                </div>
            </router-link>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


export default {
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                items: [
                    {title: 'Android', icon: <i class="fab fa-android mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>},
                    {title: 'IOS', icon: <i class="fab fa-apple mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>}
                ]
            }
        },
        components:{
            Header
        }
    }
`
```

Comment: `:v-html="item.icon"` ?

Comment: It wont work man

`<div  class="card Fcard d-flex  flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="padding: 1rem 2rem !important">
    <span :v-html="item.icon"> </span>
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
</div>


return {
    items: [
        {title: 'Android', icon: '<i class="fab fa-android mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>'},
        {title: 'IOS', icon: '<i class="fab fa-apple mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>' }
    ]
}`

Comment: All icons from items should be in string format: `icon: "<i>my-icon</i>"`

Comment: I already do that, no errors but icon doesnt show `items: [
                    {title: 'Android', icon: '<i class="fab fa-android mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>'},
                    {title: 'IOS', icon: '<i class="fab fa-apple mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem;" ></i>' }
                ]
            }`

Comment: Inspect elements in dev tools, check if `<i>...</i>` exists in **span**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icon: <i class=...` is JSX syntax that creates an element and needs to be used with render function instead of a template. It should be a string, `icon: '<i class=...'`.

There is no `icon` property, it should be `<span v-html="item.icon">`.

It's impractical to specify the whole icon element. If only `<i>` classes differ, it can be `icon: 'fa-android'`, and be used with:

```
<i class="class="fab mx-3 img-fluid" style="font-size: 1.5rem" :class="item.icon"/>
```